# CosmosDB sql query with/without "ORDER BY" returns different number of items

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm querying a cosmosdb sql database from my web service. Simply by calling:

```cs
//Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.18.0.0
DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection, query,
                    new FeedOptions {EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).AsEnumerable();
```

Now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Grade
FROM c
WHERE c.Grade > 10
AND c.Category = "A"
ORDER BY c.Name
```

I get 1000 entries back. Now if I remove the "ORDER BY" part I get 6000 rows back!!
Am I missing something? or is this a major bug in the API?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` should not be changing the number or rows returned (unless you have a `select top with ties` somewhere).

Comment: Should we assume 'ORDERY BY' is just a typo and the original code says order by?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, thanks .. fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is related to the value of `Name` field in your documents. I tested for multiple types of `Name` in sample documents.

After execute sql : `select c.id,c.itemName from c`, the results as below:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "itemName": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "itemName": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "itemName": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "itemName": [
            {
                "test": "for test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "itemName": {
            "test": "for test"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "itemName": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "7"
    }
]
```

As above documents, you could see :

itemName 1 2 3 are normal.

itemName 4 is an object.

itemName 5 is an array.

itemName 6 is "".

itemName 7 is undefined.

Then executed sql : `select c.id,c.itemName from c order by c.itemName`, the results as below:

[image]

itemName 4 5 7 didn't show up. So I think obj ,array and undefined value can't be ordered by with the normal string value. It's the reason for your issue.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm not sure if I should consider this a bug or not; as 'order by' can throw errors, or fail to sort things, but it shouldn't affect the number of entries. Thanks for helping to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Grade FROM c WHERE c.Grade > 10 AND c.Category = "A" order by c.Name
```

Run sample queries on **[cosmosdb playground](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo)** and check

Comment: Everything looks ok in the playground. I suspect this is related to my specific collection. Could it be that the "Name" field has mixed uncompatible types between entries? Maybe some entries are "object" or "undefined" while others are "strings"

Comment: however orderby wont make any difference , you need to check the documents