# Querying CosmosDB Child Collection using ORDER BY

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Say I have a document like below for each userId. And each userId has a child collection object named "lnk" and it can grow up to 100 items per userId.

I would like to sort the child collection for a given userId based on a single property
(ex: Topic or Pid or URL). for userId =  "5663a8f7-6d2e-40ef-8972-515944080474"

```sql
SELECT * FROM c IN PageLinksContainer.lnk order by c.top asc OFFSET 1 LIMIT  3
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Failed to query item for container PageLinksContainer:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "severity": "Error",
      "location": {
        "start": 7,
        "end": 25
      },
      "code": "SC2001",
      "message": "Identifier 'PageLinksContainer' could not be resolved."
    },
    {
      "severity": "Error",
      "location": {
        "start": 67,
        "end": 85
      },
      "code": "SC2001",
      "message": "Identifier 'PageLinksContainer' could not be resolved."
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
    "userid": "5663a8f7-6d2e-40ef-8972-515944080474",
    "lnk": [
        {
            "pid": 1,
            "top": "Topic 1",
            "por": "www.google.com",
            "sdt": "10/26/2021"
        },
        {
            "pid": 2,
            "top": "Topic 2",
            "por": "www.google.com",
            "sdt": "10/26/2021"
        },
        {
            "pid": 3,
            "top": "Topic 3",
            "por": "www.google.com",
            "sdt": "10/26/2021"
        }
    ]
}
```

C#

```
 var query = "SELECT * FROM c IN PageLinksContainer.lnk OFFSET 1 LIMIT  10"; //Works fine with no order by.

 var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_databaseName, containerName);

 using var iterator = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(new QueryDefinition(query),
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("5663a8f7-6d2e-40ef-8972-515944080474"),
                    MaxItemCount = 100
                });
```

Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-order-by

[CosmosDB sql query with/without "ORDER BY" returns different number of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376177/cosmosdb-sql-query-with-without-order-by-returns-different-number-of-items)

Answer (score 1):

You can't `ORDER BY` properties in arrays currently.

The following query better demonstrates that with the following error `Order-by over correlated collections is not supported`:

```
SELECT VALUE l
FROM c
JOIN l IN c.lnk
ORDER BY l.por
```

What you can do is create a User Defined Function that sorts the array before return. Although I would advise you to retrieve the results and use `OrderBy` in your C# code as it's easier, more transparant, and avoids spending unnecessary RU's on an UDF.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking the same getting 100 results and use order by in C# I can easily do it.  Thanks.
BTW- I could not vote for your answer as I don't have enough reputation. I will do it later.